# React component doesn't change state when react router remounts it

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have react router that renders different component. It looks like this:

```
ReactDOM.render(
        <Provider store={store}>
                <Router>
                        <div>
                                <Route exact path="/" component={ListPage}/>
                                <Route path="/edit/:itemId" component={ItemPage}/>
                        </div>
                </Router>
        </Provider>,
        document.getElementById('root')
);
```

So - when I open the edit page - the component renders and on mounting I'm fetching the data for that item. I'm setting it in the state, so the component renders.

Then - I go back to listing page and open edit page for another item - and when the edit page mounts again - it has the same state as before.

Why is this happening? Shouldn't the edit page start fresh, with the default state, each time the router mounts it?

(For now I'm working around this with resetting the state  on `componentDidMount()`, but it looks ugly solution to me.)

Answer (score 3):

This should fix your issue.

```
ReactDOM.render(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={ListPage}/>
            <Route path="/edit/:itemId" component={ItemPage}/>
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </Provider>,
   document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you've done and why this solves the issue?

Comment: @sigmus if you don't use Switch both the Routes are rendered, this happens because route `/` is an exact match and the `/edit/` route also starts with `/` thus both the routes will get rendered. Using Switch whichever is the first matched route only that will get rendered. 
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch